# Multiple versions of the package in node_modules, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules

I'm using package `datamaps` installed with npm. This package is havily using `d3` pacakge version 3.

And now I want to use d3js directly in my project, but version 5.

So I tried to do `npm install d3`.
But what I found is that inside node_modules d3 directory was overriden (from version 3 to version 5) and `datamaps` stop working correctly.

How can I handle this usecase? Maybe I should use not npm but some other package manager? Or I just missing something?

Comment: what version of npm are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.5.2

Comment: try running `npm shrinkwrap` in your root, then checkout the generated file (`npm-shrinkwrap.json`), make sure in your root `dependencies`, `datamaps` 's d3 and your d3 versions are correctly set, then try `npm install` again

Comment: I'm quite sure newer version of npm won't behave like this, but if upgrade is not an option you might try to use shrinkwrap like I mention above